# imagesc showing NaN values as not NaN

Tags: matlab, nan

The red patch in the following image shows the domain of a numerical model. The green patch shows the Earth.

[image: domain of the numerical model]

I want to create a matrix with the values of height above the Earth surface for the points in the model domain.

I use the following code:

```
close all
clear all

%%%slope coefficient
a=1/50;

%%%resolution
dx = 500;
dz = 2.5;

%%%define domain
xi = 0:dx:200e3;
zi = 0:dz:6e2;
m=length(zi);%domain dimension
n=length(xi);%domain dimension

%%%max z where the slope starts
zs = find(zi==max(zi)); 


for ii=1:n %for every x

    zslope = -a*xi(ii)+zi(zs);%equation of the slope

    zz(ii)=zslope;
   if zslope>=0 %if the slope is still in the domain (z>0)
     for jj=1:m %for every z

       if zi(jj)>=zslope %above the slope

         Z(jj,ii) = zi(jj)-zslope; %height above the slope

       elseif zi(jj)<zslope %below the slope (ground)

         Z(jj,ii)=NaN; 

       end
     end%for on z

   elseif zslope<0 %the slope is no longer in the domain

       for jj=1:m %for every z

          Z(jj,ii) = zi(jj)-zslope; %height above the slope

       end
   end
end%for on x
```

That seems to work fine:

```
figure;
imagesc(Z)
colorbar
```

[image: Z values]

in fact the value at point 240 is 600 as one would expect.

*THE PROBLEM*

The problem is that in the workspace the `Z` matrix is full of `NaN`s!

*How can `imagesc` show not `NaN` values when they are `NaN`s?*

**note**

if I comment the lines

```
elseif zi(jj)<zslope %below the slope (ground)

     Z(jj,ii)=NaN;
```

there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NaN` are displayed as the lowest value in colorbar (inf the opposite).  If you want to remove the NaN values from the plot you can do that by utilising `isnan` and the `AlphaData` property.

```
imagesc(Z,'AlphaData',~isnan(Z))
```